# MS-Access send records to Excel and Count Records in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have an access form with a button to send a record set to excel.

It works 70% of the time but for some reason I get an error "Runtime error '1004' Method 'Rows' of object '_Global' Failed".

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlwb As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim xlrng As Excel.Range

rst.open [Select Query]
```

Loop through record set and copy values

```
i = 2
            
Do Until rst.EOF
    dblTotHr = rst!Hours
                
    i = 2
            
    Do Until rst.EOF
        dblTotHr = rst!Hours
                
        xlws.Range("a" & i).Value = rst!A
        xlws.Range("b" & i).Value = rst!B
        xlws.Range("c" & i).Value = rst!C
                
        i = i + 1
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop
```

Code that fails (sometimes):

```
lrow = xlws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Clean up:

```
xlApp.Visible = True
Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlwb = Nothing
Set xlws = Nothing
Set xlrng = Nothing
Set rst = Nothing
Set rst1 = Nothing
```

Since this code works sometimes and not others with no pattern, I am confused on where to try and start looking for answers.

Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is

```
lrow = xlws.Cells(xlws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Otherwise you cannot be sure `Rows` refers to the sheet `xlws`. Interesting that it sometimes resp. quite often works.

If you use `Rows` in a VBA code within Excel it refers to the `ActiveSheet`  unless you add an explicit reference. This can even cause issues in Excel as the `ActiveSheet` can be a diagramm.

> To automate Microsoft Excel, you establish an object variable that usually refers to the Excel Application object or the Excel Workbook object. Other object variables can then be set to refer to a Worksheet, a Range, or other objects in the Microsoft Excel object model. When you write code to use an Excel object, method, or property, you should always precede the call with the appropriate object variable. If you do not, Visual Basic establishes its own reference to Excel. This reference might cause problems when you try to run the automation code multiple times. Note that even if the line of code begins with the object variable, a call may be made to an Excel object, method, or property in the middle of the line of code that is not preceded with an object variable.

Further [reading](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/excel-automation-fails-second-time-code-runs-6647c4b4-da5c-ee1f-cc6f-58815d47702d)

Comment: I didn't realize I needed another worksheet reference there. thank you!